# How to copy columns within same worksheet Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a program that needs to copy select columns within the same workbook and worksheet. 
The current code results in Excel crashing, so I'm not sure if it is working or not.

Is there a better way to copy the columns within the same worksheets with the same workbook?

Code:

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim wb1 As Workbook

'Set it to be the file location, name, and file extension of the Working File
Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open("Z:\XXX\Working File.xlsx")

MsgBox "Copying Fields within Working File"

wb1.Worksheets(1).Columns("G").Copy wb1.Worksheets(1).Columns("H").Value
wb1.Worksheets(1).Columns("J").Copy wb1.Worksheets(1).Columns("O").Value
wb1.Worksheets(1).Columns("K").Copy wb1.Worksheets(1).Columns("N").Value
wb1.Worksheets(1).Columns("M").Copy wb1.Worksheets(1).Columns("P").Value

wb1.Close SaveChanges:=True

End Sub
```

Comment: Take off the `.Value` at the end. You just want to copy to a range, not Value.  But, if you just need values and not formatting/etc, you can just do `Range([Destination Range]).Value = Range([copy range]).Value`, i.e. `wb1.Worksheets(1).Columns("H").Value = wb1.Worksheets(1).Columns("G").Value`. Also, do you need to use the whole column?

Comment: Ah, I added that because the client wanted to have a paste values only option, and I thought that was how you could do that

Comment: I do need the whole column

Comment: It is very rare that you need the whole column, that's 1048576 cells these days, the majority of which will be empty.

Comment: Its for a call desk department that wants it that way lol 
The column length may vary overtime, so that's why they want the whole column

Comment: @DylanF - We can handle that with a simple line or two. If the rows change over time, you just need to get the `lastRow` for each column. But for now, if it works, it works!

Comment: You can still speed things up by just copying all the cells from row 1 to the last used row in the worksheet - that may be only 10000 rows, but will be possibly 100 times quicker than copying all 1000000 rows.  There is really no point in changing 990000 cells from empty to empty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this, it sets two ranges' values equal, which will keep the data, but no formatting. It should be quicker.

```
Sub Macro1()
Dim wb1 As Workbook
'Set it to be the file location, name, and file extension of the Working File
Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open("Z:\XXX\Working File.xlsx")

MsgBox "Copying Fields within Working File"

With wb1.Worksheets(1)
    .Columns("H").Value = .Columns("G").Value
    .Columns("O").Value = .Columns("J").Value
    .Columns("N").Value = .Columns("K").Value
    .Columns("P").Value = .Columns("M").Value
End With

wb1.Close SaveChanges:=True

End Sub
```

Note you're using a *whole column*, so it might hang up or take a little longer. If you want, you can instead just get the last Row of each column and use that to shorten the ranges being copied.

Edit: As mentioned above, you may be better off using a smaller range. This is a little more verbose, but you should be able to follow what it's doing:

```
Sub Macro1()
Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim lastRow As Long
'Set it to be the file location, name, and file extension of the Working File
Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook

MsgBox "Copying Fields within Working File"

With wb1.Worksheets(1)
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("H1:H" & lastRow).Value = .Range("G1:G" & lastRow).Value

    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("O1:O" & lastRow).Value = .Range("J1:J" & lastRow).Value

    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("N1:N" & lastRow).Value = .Range("K1:K" & lastRow).Value

    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("P1:P" & lastRow).Value = .Range("M1:M" & lastRow).Value
End With

wb1.Close SaveChanges:=True

End Sub
```

Comment: 12 to go - get an "accepted answer" here and you will have made it!

Comment: Thank you!
This worked, and like you said, it took a little but it meets the client's needs

Comment: Congratulations Bruce!!

Comment: @YowE3K and everyone - [Thanks! :D](https://media.giphy.com/media/FGmbEOTVWQHzW/giphy.gif)